# Why does optional chaining allows rendering when fetching data through useEffect in an app that uses context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-context

I'm new to the webdev world and want to learn ReactJS. I followed a tutorial I found on YouTube made by Traversy where he makes a task tracker and now I want to make some changes to it to learn and practice some more.

I want to use context for the appointments (originally named tasks in the tutorial), add a calendar with react-calendar and use react-router-dom.
I got stuck for a while trying to make the list render, because it only rendered "empty". Later on found this post with a similar issue to mine: [Only run a useEffect fetch after first useEffect fetch has fired and setUser in context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66736451/only-run-a-useeffect-fetch-after-first-useeffect-fetch-has-fired-and-setuser-in)

I changed bits of my code based on that post and now it does render the appointment list, but I don't know why it didn't work before and I'm unsure on why it does work now. I don't even know if I'm using context correctly or just prop-drilling. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Also, sorry if my code is a mess, I'm new at this.

**App.js**

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Dashboard from "./views/Dashboard";
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import AddAppointmentForm from "./views/AddAppointmentForm";

export const AppContext = createContext();
export const AppUpdateContext = createContext();

function App() {
  const [appointments, setAppointments] = useState([])
  const updateAppointments = (apptList) => {
    setAppointments(apptList)
  }

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={ appointments }>
      <AppUpdateContext.Provider value={ updateAppointments }>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            
              <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard appointments={appointments} />} />
              {/* <Route path="/add" element={<AddAppointmentForm />} />  TBA */} 
            
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </AppUpdateContext.Provider>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
import { useEffect, useContext} from "react";
import { AppContext } from "../App";
import { AppUpdateContext } from "../App";
import AppointmentList from "../components/AppointmentList";
import Header from "../components/Header";

// function Dashboard() {  // this is how it used to be
  function Dashboard(props) {
  const appointments = useContext(AppContext)
  const setAppointments = useContext(AppUpdateContext)

  const fetchAppointmentList = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/appointments");
    const data = await res.json();

    return data;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAppointments = async () => {
      const appointmentsFromServer = await fetchAppointmentList();
      setAppointments(appointmentsFromServer);
    }

    getAppointments();
    console.log("ñññññ",appointments)
  }, []);
  
  console.log("aagh",appointments)
  
  return (
    <div style={dashboardStyle}>
      <Header />
      {/* {appointments.lenght>0 ? (<AppointmentList />) : <p>empty</p>} this is how it used to be */}
      <AppointmentList appointments={props?.appointments}/>
    </div>
  );
}

const dashboardStyle = {
  maxWidth: "31.25rem",
  overflow: "auto",
  minHeight: "18.75rem",
  border: "1px solid steelblue",
  margin: "1.875rem auto",
  padding: ".5rem",
  boxSizing: "border-box",
}

export default Dashboard;
```

**AppointmentList.js**

```
import Appointment from "./Appointment";
import { AppContext } from "../App";
import { useContext } from "react";

function AppointmentList({ appointments }) {
// function AppointmentList() {  // this is how it used to be
  // const { appointments, setAppointments } = useContext(AppContext)
  console.log("appList",appointments)  // this is how it used to be

  return (
    <>
      {
        appointments.map(appt => (
          <Appointment key={appt.id} appointment={appt} />
        ))
      }
    </>
  );
}

export default AppointmentList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does optional chaining allows rendering when fetching data through
> useEffect in an app that uses context?
>
> ```
> <AppointmentList appointments={props?.appointments}/>
> ```

It allows rendering by preventing accidental accesses into potentially null or undefined objects. The only way `props` could be undefined though is if you just simply don't declare it, i.e. `const Dashboard = () => {....` vs `const Dashboard = (props) => {....`.

You are drilling the `appointments` state through props. `AppointmentList`  can use the `AppContext` context to access the `appointments` state, while `Dashboard` can use the `AppUpdateContext` context to update the `appointments` state.

App

```
function App() {
  const [appointments, setAppointments] = useState([]);
  const updateAppointments = (apptList) => {
    setAppointments(apptList);
  };

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ appointments }}> // <-- need object here
      <AppUpdateContext.Provider value={{ updateAppointments }}> // <-- and here
        <Router>
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} /> // <-- don't pass props
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </AppUpdateContext.Provider>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Dashboard

```
function Dashboard() { // <-- no props
  const { updateAppointments } = useContext(AppUpdateContext); // <-- access from context

  const fetchAppointmentList = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/appointments");
    const data = await res.json();

    return data;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAppointments = async () => {
      const appointmentsFromServer = await fetchAppointmentList();
      updateAppointments(appointmentsFromServer);
    }

    getAppointments();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={dashboardStyle}>
      <Header />
      <AppointmentList /> // <-- don't pass props
    </div>
  );
}
```

AppointmentList

```
function AppointmentList() { // <-- no props
  const { appointments } = useContext(AppContext); // <-- access from context

  return appointments.map(appt => (
    <Appointment key={appt.id} appointment={appt} />
  ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much! I had been stuck on this for a couple of days and now it works the way I wanted! Thank you!
Just a few oversights from your answer that needed to be addressed:
In _Dashboard_ should be `const { updateAppointments } = useContext(AppUpdateContext)`
Also in _Dashboard_, inside the useEffect: `updateAppointments(appointmentsFromServer);`
In _AppointmentList_ should be: `const { appointments } = useContext(AppContext);`
Anyway, it works! And it's cleaner! I'm pretty sure I'll run into another wall sooner than later, but for now I'm happy that this works. Thanks again!

Comment: @miguelC Oops, sorry, that was largely copy/pasted. Will double check and clean up. Cheers.